# Realm.getDefaultModule() returns null

Tags: android, realm

Following the instructions [here](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#schemas), 
I tried to set 2 modules for my main realm, AccountModule and TripModule are classes in their respective projects (they sit in their own projects)

```
@RealmModule(library = true, allClasses = true)
public class AccountModule {
    //nothing here
}




@RealmModule(library = true, allClasses = true)
public class TripModule {
    //nothing here
}
```

and in the application project, I wired them up like this:

```
RealmConfiguration configDeleteIfNeeded = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this.getActivity())
                .name("app.realm")
                .setModules(Realm.getDefaultModule(), new AccountModule(), new TripModule())
                .build();
```

However `Realm.getDefaultModule()` always returns null and throws the error Provided RealmModule must not be null. What am I missing? 
Thanks

**Update:** like @beener's comment, the workaround is like below:

I created a dummy module with a dummy class in the application project, now getDefaultModule() is not null and it works

Comment: So you have 3 projects? One lib project for AccountModule, one lib project for TripModule, and another application project for the defaultModule, right? Do you define any your own module in the application project? If so `Doing so prevents the default RealmModule from being generated for the library project, which would otherwise conflict with the default RealmModule being generated by the app`

Comment: @beeender No I don't have any Realm module in my application project

Comment: It might be a bug... I created a github issue https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1302 to track it. Meanwhile, if you need a workaround, i think you can define a RealmModule in the app project as well.

Comment: @beeender awesome tip, I created a dummy module with a dummy class in the application project, now getDefaultModule() is not null and it works!

Comment: @tung-mai-lei Uh... now i am confused. Now it is like you defined a dummy module in the app project, and the `getDefaultModule` doesn't return null anymore? That doesn't seem to be the desired behaviour. I was supposed to ask you have a `DummyModule` in the app project, and call new `DummyModule` instead.

Comment: that's right, with the DummyModule in, now getDefaultModule() doesn't return null anymore, it looks like a bug but that's how it is right now, my realm version is 0.8.1.1

Comment: @TungMeiLe Is there any reason you want to use the default module? The above error should only happen if you application project doesn't contain any Realm classes at all, in which case adding the default module doesn't do anything anyway?